# Subframe staticset.com causing high CPU usage in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Hi I notice that when I checked my chrome task manager that subframe staticset.com causes high CPU usage. Is there a way to know what causes of this? and is there a way to check for plugins and extensions that causing problems with high CPU usage? what does subframes do?

Comment: The developer console might help you. It has a script and network debugger that can show you the assets of a site. Maybe you can gain some information from there.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a mining websit.I con't open it(502).I just try to direct this domain name to 127.0.0.1 but I don't know if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Press shift+Esc, double-click the Subframe staticset.com, find the plug-in, and uninstall it. The problem is caused by plug-ins.